# Are there fundamental differences between TextBoxes in Windows 7 and Windows XP

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, keyboard

I've written a windows forms app in .Net 4.0 that utilizes a text box for user input. The intent of the program is to accept input from a stenography machine; through which a transcriber would be actively captioning live video.

The problem I am experiencing is that in Windows XP environments, the text box is performing as expected, accepting QWERTY keyboard input, as well as input from the stenography machine. It's my understanding that the machine integrates as the equivalent of another keyboard, but for some reason in Windows 7, the text box is accepting input from the QWERTY board, but not from the Stenography machine.

This brings me to the question at hand - are there any fundamental differences between a text box in Windows 7 and Windows XP, and amongst those are there any that could affect the manner in which it handles text from the OS?

Thanks much, I hope I've been explicit enough.

Comment: Functionally, they should be the same.  Any chance the Win 7 version the TextBox doesn't have the focus?

Comment: Well that's upsetting to hear - the Win 7 version most definitely has focus. The windows 7 version will actually accept QWERTY input, but not Steno input. Will update OP.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong corner for this problem.  What has changed is the kind of OS feature this stenography machine would use to poke text into a TextBox.  Like a journaling hook.  UAC can put a stop to that for example.  This requires blind guessing, contact the vendor for support.

Comment: If the machine acts just like a keyboard, does it work with NotePad?

Comment: I think Hans has it right.  This isn't a problem with the TextBox receiving data, it's the way in which it's being fed.  The "equivalent of another keyboard" isn't good enough.  Learn the way it's trying to do the work and you'll find your perpetrator.

Comment: Well thank you gentlemen for the input. @LarsTech, I can say that the Steno keyboard works in Word on the Windows 7 system - and is known to work in other programs as well. I can also state that my end-user is initializing the program as the administrator.

Comment: I agree with Hans. Are the two applications running under the same Session? Is your textbox program UAC Virtualization true/false or DEP true/false, and what about stenograph? These are fields you can see in Task Manager if you're under 'Processes', go to View, Select Columns.

Comment: this maybe got nothing to do .NET, but the device driver on the OS.
Apart from your code/.NET, is there other way to test the stenography machine on Win7 working as expected?

Comment: Another comment agreeing with Hans. I had a related problem in regards to drag-drop from Windows Explorer to WinForms app. If the app was running as Admin while the Windows Explorer was running as default user drag-drop just would not work due to UAC enforcing security on clipboard operations. You might find a work-around by playing around with which user runs the service for the Steno input.

Comment: I would focus on the Drivers side of the Stenography machine. I've worked mostly with Barcode Scanners as alternate input devices, so these are some of the things I consider. 

 - Does it work without drivers? Sometimes drivers complicate things they don't need too.
 - How does it connect to the computer? USB?
 - What type of device does it show up as in the Device Manager?

Answer (score 1):

To give a final answer to the actual question.

The Winforms TextBox is still the same wrapped Win32 class "Edit". All known methods of feeding a TextBox works just as well from XP all the way to Win10 today - WM_KEYDOWN messages, Keybd_event, SendKeys.

The only known changes having an impact would be security and driver model.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with the text box. Try updating your .NET Framework to the latest version. You could also try using a rich text box instead, or try a stenography machine in the console (in XP and 7). Hopefully this helps solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such difference due to operating system on TextBox. TextBox Have its property same for both OS (there is no special property of TextBox to get input from different source like keyboard,stenography machine or anything else), Yes there is possibly you got error/problem if you are not use updated Framework, First Update your system and check it again. You may go through this [microsoft link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx)